# Next-auth CredentialProvider config and redirect

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-auth

I'm a bit confused on the implementation of the credentials provider and the redirects. The documentation says that the credentials provider doesn't support a callback and its for the OAuth providers. This is fine. However, instead of staying on the page and flashing an error message or even logging in like in [this video](https://youtu.be/im8o328q6EI?t=859) it redirects to `https://localhost/api/auth/callback/[credentials-provider-name]`. Which doesn't even include the port I'm working with. If I explicitly set an id it uses that at the end of the url in instead.

This is what I have for the provider

```js
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials"

export default NextAuth({
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      credentials: {
        username: { label: "Username", type: "text", placeholder: "someuser69" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      name: "User Pass",
      type: "credentials",
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        // Add logic here to look up the user from the credentials supplied
        return {
          id: 2,
          name: "user",
          email: "user@gmail.com",
        }
        return null;
      }
    })
    // ...add more providers here
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, account }) {
      // Persist the OAuth access_token to the token right after signin
      if (account) {
        token.accessToken = account.access_token
      }
      return token
    },
    async session({ session, token, user }) {
      // Send properties to the client, like an access_token from a provider.
      session.accessToken = token.accessToken
      return session
    },
    async redirect({ url, baseUrl, }) {
      console.log("");
      return baseUrl;
    },
    async signIn({ user, account, profile, email, credentials }) {
      return '/home';
    }
  },
  session: {
    jwt: true,
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60,

  },
  secret: "CHANGE!!!",
  jwt: {
    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
    secret: "afdsfi",

  },

})
```

I've looked through the docs and I'm not sure if I'm making some massive oversight, here. But some of my major confusions are:

- Where is this callback set and how do I turn in off in the default provider (if possible).
- I don't think the `authorize` function works. If I put a console log in it. It doesn't print to the terminal. So I don't even know if it's being called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that I hadn't set the `NEXTAUTH_URL` variable correctly. The module apparently appends `https` if the protocol isn't set in the provided address. This is the case whether you are using `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`. The solution to fixing the callback issues is to pass in the unsecured `http` protocol if you're using a local address for testing or development purposes like so:

`NEXTAUTH_URL='http://127.0.0.1:3001'`